Convert COUNIF formula used for Data Validation (Custom formula is) to AppScript to be used as Custom Formula
I have a formula as
=COUNTIF(col_Customers_Categories_Ids, B4)<=1
Where
col_Customers_Categories_Ids refers to the open ended range Customers Categories'!B4:B
Using Data Validation > Custom formula is =COUNTIF(col_Customers_Categories_Ids, B4)<=1 applied to range Customers Categories'!B4:B I can ensure that no duplicates are allowed / only unique values can be entered.
How can i convert this to AppScript where I can use IsUnique(range, cell) where the custom fucntion is defined. I tried the below but it does not work.
function IsUnique(range, cell) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rangeValues = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();
  
  // Flatten the rangeValues array and filter out empty values
  var values = rangeValues.flat().filter(value => value !== '');

  // Count the occurrences of the cell value in the range
  var count = values.filter(value => value === cellValue).length;

  // If the count is greater than 1, it's not unique
  return count < 2;
}


This returns Invalid The cell content violates its validation rules and does not allow me to enter any values.
The intention is to have multiple validation rule such as
function IsText(cell) {
  return typeof cell === 'string';
}

and than use =AND(IsUnique(range, cell), IsText(cell))
I tried both custom function and named functions as Is_Text() and Is_Unique() for App Script and IS_TEXT() and IS_UNIQUE() for Named functions and both cases it works. Just not =Is_Unique() so it has to do with the logic of the =Is_Unique()

Is-Text() and Is-Unique() are invalid custom function names.

Is_Text() and Is_Unique() for App Script and IS_TEXT() and IS_UNIQUE() for Named functions

As I mentioned, Google Sheets formulas are case-insensitive for function names (including custom function names and named functions). Please consider this when naming your custom functions and named functions.

Data > Data validation custom formula rules do not work with custom functions.
It would probably be easiest to implement the rule with plain vanilla Google Sheets functions, like this:
=and(istext(B4), 1 = countif(B$4:B, B4))

To answer the question, the most important issue in the code is that it assumes that its parameters are range references when they are actually passed as values. You can fix that like this:
/**
* Does the exact same thing as `=1 = countif(range, cell)`,
* with no obvious difference other than being slower.
* 
* @param {B$4:B} range The cells to compare against.
* @param {B4} cell The values to count.
* @customfunction
*/
function IsSingle(range, cell) {
  const values = range.flat().filter(String);
  return 1 === values.filter(value => value === cell).length;
}

That will not make it work in a data validation rule, though.

I tried both custom function and named functions as =Is-Text() and both cases it works. Just not =Is-Unique() so it has to do with the logic of the =Is-Unique()

Is_Text() and Is_Unique() for App Script and IS_TEXT() and IS_UNIQUE() for Named functions

You're correct, named functions work in data validation custom formula rules, but custom functions, the kind you write with Apps Script, do not seem to work there.

Custom functions don't work in data validation custom formulas.
It's worth mentioning that it's impossible to use IsText for a custom function because a Google Sheets function is already named ISTEXT. So that you know, Google Sheets formulas are case-insensitive regarding function names.
If you need to use Apps Script for data validation, then instead of using the Google Sheets data validation feature, try using an on-edit trigger.
Just to let you know, on-edit triggers have limitations. Simple triggers are more limited than installable triggers, but both might not work well in some cases. If the on-edit triggers don't work, consider using a custom menu or a time-driven trigger to run the data validation Apps Script function.

I tried both custom function and named functions as =Is-Text() and both cases it works. Just not =Is-Unique() so it has to do with the logic of the =Is-Unique()

@ProcurementMosaic  Is-Text() and Is-Unique() are invalid custom function names.

Is_Text() and Is_Unique() for App Script and IS_TEXT() and IS_UNIQUE() for Named functions
